# Where is tcl-doc man page stored?

Tags: debian, package-management, man, dpkg

I installed tcl-doc. Prior to installation "man tcl" gave nothing. Now it gives a page.

When I do 
"dpkg -L tcl-doc" I get

```
/.  
/usr  
/usr/share  
/usr/share/doc  
/usr/share/doc/tcl-doc 
/usr/share/doc/tcl-doc/tcltk-policy.html 
/usr/share/doc/tcl-doc/tcltk-policy.pdf 
/usr/share/doc/tcl-doc/README.Debian 
/usr/share/doc/tcl-doc/copyright 
/usr/share/doc/tcl-doc/tcltk-policy.txt.gz 
/usr/share/doc/tcl-doc/changelog.Debian.gz
```

I am wondering what the source of the output of the command "man tcl" is? Is it  one of the above files, and if not, why isn't it displayed in the above output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tcl-doc` recommends `tcl-8.5-doc` on wheezy or later and `tcl8.4-doc` on squeeze which contains the manpages. To see the included manpages have a look at [the filelist for tcl8.4-doc](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/all/tcl8.4-doc/filelist).

So `tcl-doc` does not contain any manpage but the recommends is installed automatically by the package manager which contains the manpage.

Comment: What is "tcl-docs"?

Comment: @Scooter it is `tcl-doc`

Comment: I am not sure about the use of the term "recommends". My Software Manager says "tcl-doc" "is a depedency package, which depends on Debian's default Tcl version (currently 8.5)" Apparently "tcl8.5-doc" gets installed if you install "tcl-doc". It seems that "dpkg -L" does not give info for other packages that are installed when you installed the one you are asking about. Anyway, if I do "dpkg -L tcl8.5-doc" it does show where the man pages went/are.

Comment: @Scooter it is an official Debian term - see the debian [package site for tcl-doc](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/tcl-doc). See [the debian manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html#s-depends) for more information about depends/suggests/recommends.

Answer (score 1):

The man command on several systems has a `-w` and a `-W` option that prints the path of the man source for the requested topic.  Therefore something like `main -w tcl` would show where the tcl man page source file is located.

Comment: Good idea to point out `man -w`, but in this case it's not a helpful answer, since the question is about `tcl-doc` man page, not `tcl` man page, and (as noted in the accepted answer) `tcl-doc` doesn't have a man page. So this doesn't really answer the question. It'd be OK as a comment, but you need to earn some [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) before commenting is allowed. Please see the Answering- and Asking -questions in the [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to get a handle on how SE sites work.